# Hibernate всегда вытаскивает сущность из связанной таблицы по id сущности главной таблицы

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate

Проблема такая, вот вывод всех Writers:

```
[Writer{id=1, firstName='', lastName='', post=[Post{id=1, content='textupdate', created=63335, updated=366644, postStatus=ACTIVE}]
```

Если будем вытаскивать Writer, чей id = 2, то у него будет и Post c id = 2.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "post", schema = "public")
public class Post {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "post_id")
    private Long id;
    @Column(name = "content")
    private String content;
    @Column(name = "created")
    @Convert(converter = TimeStampToLongConverter.class)
    private Long created;
    @Column(name = "updated")
    @Convert(converter = TimeStampToLongConverter.class)
    private Long updated;
    @Column(name = "post_status")
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private PostStatus postStatus;

@Entity
@Table(name = "writer", schema = "public")
public class Writer {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column (name = "writer_id")
    private Long id;
    @Column (name = "firstname")
    private String firstName;
    @Column (name = "lastname")
    private String lastName;
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "post_id")
    private List<Post> post;
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "region_id")
    private Region region;


public class PostDAOImpl implements PostRepository {
    @Override
    public List<Post> getAll() {
        Session session = null;
        List <Post> postList = null;
        try {
            session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().withOptions().
                    jdbcTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC")).openSession();
            CriteriaBuilder builder = session.getCriteriaBuilder();
            CriteriaQuery<Post> criteriaQuery = builder.createQuery(Post.class);
            criteriaQuery.from(Post.class);

            postList = session.createQuery(criteriaQuery).getResultList();
        }catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println(e);
        } finally {
            if (session != null && session.isOpen()) {
                session.close();
            }
        }
        return postList;
    }
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: а какого результата вы хотели добиться? Чтобы получить "у 1 writer много post" нужно, чтобы у Post был внешний ключ, ссылающийся на ID writer. А вы в качестве внешнего ключа указали ID Post, т.е. фактически получили отношение 1:1

Comment: можете поподробнее?! ведь Post's не должны знать, какие Writer содержат их, односторонняя связь же?

Comment: не особо понял вопрос. Что именно не так?